# Can't extract geo keys when inserting large polygon

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I have been battling this for the past 2 days and can't seem to get it working.

I have the polygon in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tomaskallup/5f3174bdc41336322442dcb57edabb62), which I'm trying to insert into collection with '2dsphere' index on the polygon field. I've gone through quite a few itterations, removing some points from the polygon, trying to sort it so that it's 100% counter-clockwise (which resulted in malformed polygon) and mongo still won't let me insert it. The error I'm seeing is just `Can't extract geo keys:` without any extra information at the end.

I went for help to geo json validator, which told me, that I need to have the first point at the end of the polygon, but that results in a `Edges 0 and 395 cross.`. I'm kinda getting hopeless, as I have about 1000 of these polygons from external API and can't go through them 1 by 1. Also the wierd thing is, if I swap latitude with longitude, mongo is able to insert them, but that's not a solution, even the documentation says **longitude** first. And as can be observed in the gist, pretty much every map I tried can display the polygon and I wasn't able to observe any kind of "disruption" or wierd edges.

I would love if someone could point out what's wrong with the polygon or gime me a nudge in the right direction.

Also this probably shouldn't change anything, but I'm using `mongoose` and I did try to insert this polygon manualy via the `mongo shell`.